# No data being logged that is read from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text,View} from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


export class DashboardScreen extends Component {  

    static navigationOptions = {  
        title: '                 Homiess',  
    };
    componentDidMount() {
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "secret",
      authDomain: "secret",
      databaseURL: "secret",
      projectId: "secret",
      storageBucket: "secret",
      messagingSenderId: "secret",
      appId: "secret",
      measurementId: "secret"
    };
    // firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    !firebase.apps.length
      ? firebase= firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
      : firebase.app();

      firebase.database().ref('Admin').once('value',(data)=>{
        console.warn(data.toJSON);
      })
     }
      render() {  
        return (  
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>  
                <Text>DashboardScreen</Text>  
            </View>  
        );  
    }  
}
```

I am having data in firebase realtime database as Admin data and it is not logging the data as i have converted to json than also. I have inserted the data to firebase realtime database by code only .

Comment: Hey, please describe your problem more clearly, also images can be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read data from Firebase Realtime Database you get back a [`DataSnapshot` object](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/database/datasnapshot). To access the data in there, use the `val()` method:

```
firebase.database().ref('Admin').once('value',(data)=>{
  console.warn(data.val());
})
```